# Suddenly: WinError 10054 Python Socket.py dependency

Tags: python, sockets, selenium-webdriver, anaconda, ftplib

I know questions about WinError 10054 have been asked before, but solutions were not applicable in my case.

I have a dozen of scripts running on a daily basis, but as of yesterday a few of them crashed on the following error:

```
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

The scripts are both running on a local computer and a server (acceptance/production) and the strange thing is that on both machines the scripts now crash. In one case the script crashes on ftplib at the moment I try to retrieve a file from the ftp server by `ftp.retrbinary()`. Another script crashes when I try to close a webdriver, used for controlling the Chrome browser. Both are dependent on the socket.py library and the error traces back to: `return self._sock.recv_into(b)`. Has there been some update recently that could cause this error?

Comment: Update the question with the relevant _code block_ and _error stack trace_

Comment: Our counterparty did a hardware change on their FTP server. Communication by passive mode was not possible anymore, so I had to change it to active to make it work again. Still I didn't figure out why chromedriver also suddenly reported the 10054 winerror.

Comment: Glad to know your scripts are back on track. Possibly you can raise a ticket on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/tour) to get a clear understanding. Do keep me updated.